# Resusage : RSS Node logging rate decreased to 60 seconds from 600. Will that be a performance impact?

Tags: performance, resources, teradata

The RSS screen Node logging rate has been decreased to 60 seconds. Will that impact the overall performance?

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing the dumping of ResUsage data by a factor ten. This will not only have an impact on CPU and IO but will increase your space utilization in DBC. You may have to consider dumping ResUsage data from DBC to a historical database more than once a day. As such, you will incur the overhead of moving that data more than once per day.

I would consult with your CSR and the GSC as they understand the exact configuration of your platform and the workload it is managing. I have not worked in an environment that required that level of detail in resource usage logging.